# JAVA: having trouble working with arithmetic operators (code so far included)

Tags: java, string

I need to modify `evalE` and `evalMD` so that the program now can evaluate arithmetic expressions with +, -, *, / operators and positive or negative integer operands.  I have gotten it to work with basic equations, but if for example I put in equation 25+-2 I receive errors. Here is what I have so far:

```
int evalE(String exp)   
{
    int result = 0;
    String tmp="";
    char ch;

    for (int i=exp.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {   ch = exp.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '+')
        {
            result += evalMD(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        }
        else if (ch == '-')
        {
            result -= evalMD(tmp);
            tmp = "";
        }
        else
            tmp = ch+tmp;

    }

    if (exp.charAt(0) != '+' && exp.charAt(0) != '-')
         result += evalMD(tmp);

    return result;
}


int evalMD(String exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    String tmp = "";
    char previousOP = '*';

    for (int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
    {
        char ch = exp.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '*' || ch == '/')
        {
            if (previousOP == '*')
                result *= Integer.parseInt(tmp);
            else
                result /= Integer.parseInt(tmp);

            tmp = "";
            previousOP = ch;
        }
        else
            tmp = tmp+ch;
    }

    if (previousOP == '*')
        result *= Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    else
        result /= Integer.parseInt(tmp);            

    return result;
}
```

Why won't my equation work with the above mentioned circumstances? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: also, the input comes directly from user input as shown below:

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Expression myE= new Expression();
        
        for (;;)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter an expression: ");
        String e = in.next();
        
        if (e.charAt(0)=='Q' || e.charAt(0)=='q')
            break;
        
        System.out.println(e+"="+myE.evalE(e));
        }
    }  
}

Comment: Use a pool and see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, it seems that if the second number is negative at all, (regardless the operand), the program will send errors. I suggest making a scenario in which the second number, if negative, would be enclosed in parentheses. e.g. 25+(-10). By doing this, it should be a lot easier to see if there is going to be a negative. 
Also, maybe you should check your code for the division operand. It only does integer division right now, (  24/20 = 1  ) but if you want it to do a real divide, you will have to change the return type of the method to "double".